# Castle Windsor: Component for which consumer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC, Castle Windsor and Log4Net in a project.

I've got something like this in my logging component:

```
public class Log4NetLoggerService : ILoggerService
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public Log4NetLoggerService()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Log4NetLoggerService));
    }
}
```

But of course this gives me "Log4NetLoggerService" in my log files...

Now what I'd like is to find out **for which consumer class my logging component is being resolved/constructed**.

I've tried using the StackFrame class, but without luck (and not only, but also, because the logging service may either be resolved implicitly (IoC) or using a direct call to IKernel.Resolve).

There must be some way to do this in the Windsor framework, I just couldn't find anything...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just take the type in your constructor?

```
 public Log4NetLoggerService(Type loggingComponentType)
{
    _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(loggingComponentType);
}
```

If you are using the logger as a static member in your component, you will only need to send the type in once.

Comment: Because it is not constructed manually, but by Castle Windsor (IoC).

Sorry for my late reply.